How can run the IdentityServer for Macos?
I am developing a project, it is requested to use IdentityServer4. I install the project but I can't run it because it doesn't support .net 3.1 on Macos operating system.
I did some research, I found DuendeSoftware IdentityServer.Templates.
I typed this command dotnet new install Duende.IdentityServer.Templates.I did the installation but I could not create a project like in IdentityServer4.
How can I do this?

After installing the template using dotnet new install Duende.IdentityServer.Templates, you should be able to create a new Identity Server project using the dotnet new idsrv command.
Here are the steps:

Open your terminal.
Run the command dotnet new idsrv -n [projectname] to create a new Identity Server project.
Navigate using cd [project name].
Use IDE to work on the project and any additional setup or configuration steps provided by Duende Identity Server's documentation to configure your project according to your requirements.


I tried, but it gave me an error. After some research, I tried dotnet new isef -n MultiShop.IdentityServer command and the project was created.  But files such as Models, Data, QuickStart were not created.
